# HTML JS append random image in DIV

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a booster pack opening simulator

With this code it displays a random image

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <center>
    <input class="randombutton" type="button" value="Open Pack" onclick="randomImg1()"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function randomImg1() {


            myImages1 = new Array();
            myImages1[0] = "images/TradingCard.png";
            myImages1[1] = "images/TradingCard1.png";

            var rnd = Math.floor( Math.random() * myImages1.length ); //incorporated other solution

            document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='" + myImages1[rnd] + "' alt='image'></img>";
        }

        </script>
    <div id="image"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Would it be possible so when the image (The card) is generated its displayed and then when the button is pushed again it is put into a inventory of all the "Cards" you have opened so you can show other all the cards you have opened and then another card is generated and so on.

Thanks

Comment: What you mean by adding it into an inventory? can you give proper explanation what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: ok edited it. check it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append image to container instead of rewriting `innerHTML` with the new one. For example using [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method:

```
function randomImg1() {
    var myImages1 = new Array();
    myImages1[0] = "images/Myimage.png";
    myImages1[1] = "images/Myimage1.png";

    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages1.length);

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = myImages1[rnd];
    document.getElementById("image").appendChild(img);
}
```

or it can be simpler with [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method:

```
document.getElementById("image").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<img src='" + myImages1[rnd] + "' alt='image' />");
```

Also note, that you don't need `</img>` closing tag in case of `img`, but you do need `var` keyword in `myImages1` variable declaration.